# getting distances between points from a list of gps coordinates

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of that contains permutations of GPS coordinates(taking max 3 at a time)
I want the distances between these permutations.
An example would be
[pt1, pt2, pt3, p4, p5]
so I have the possible permutations of the above list and like [(pt1, pt3), (pt2,pt4)], etc. and I want the distances between these points.

I'm using the mpu pkg and I can get the dist between two points but I want to just pass my list into the function and get all the distances

```
def distcalc(a,b):
    return m.haversine_distance(a,b)
distcalc((50.3433918,3.1150847), (50.2657168,2.7968176))
output : 24.19755642690434
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a list comprehension?
Assuming your list of permutations is called `permutations`, the code would look something like this:

```
def distcalc(a,b):
    return m.haversine_distance(a,b)

permuations = [ ((50.3433918,3.1150847), (50.2657168,2.7968176)),  ((49.12328,3.5342847), (51.43267168,2.4623513)) ]
distances = [distcalc(p[0], p[1]) for p in permumations]
```

Comment: Hey andrew-g-za, thanks for your reply, I tried it but i get
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x000002609016F930> any clue how to proceed ?

Comment: What is the type of your permutations list - it should be a list of lists of tuples, or a list of tuple of tuples - i've updated the answer to be clearer

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how you could make the list of distances between any 2 points. I assume that you don't want to double count points (e.g. `(pt1, pt2)` is the same as `(pt2, pt1)`). If I am wrong in making this assumption, you can use `itertools.permutations` instead of `itertools.combinations`. You can apply the same method for 3 points as well with a slight modification to the `distcalc()` function if needed.

```py
import mpu as m
from itertools import combinations
import random

random.seed(0)
pts = [(random.uniform(50,51),random.uniform(2,4)) for _ in range(5)]

def distcalc(pts):
    return m.haversine_distance(pts[0], pts[1])

pts_combos = list(combinations(pts, 2))
pts_distances = [distcalc(combo) for combo in pts_combos]
print(pts_distances)
```

Output:

```
[84.71362807087625, 62.02569640399133, 64.23798168475103, 47.73360319424448, 22.999460663434967, 40.87224193873041, 46.36818755317338, 33.52072531697023, 25.538758765945207, 52.227892324230865]
```